# After Install Phantomjs Via NPM in Windows 8, Cannot run "phantomjs" command

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, casperjs

I got problems...
I'm using npm command from nodejs in my windows 8.1.
After installation complete, I run npm install -g casperjs, everything goes fine, no error in installment, but nothing happened when I execute casperjs --version command. Cmd said, casperjs is not recognized.
After that I try to install phantom js using npm install phantomjs command. Everything goes fine too...no error in installment. But when I try to run phantomjs command nothing happened, the cmd said "phantomjs is not recognized.
I try conventional method for installing casperjs. I'm install phantomjs 1.9.8. Set the path, after that install casperjs 1.1 beta3, set the path...but I got error "casperjs unsafe javascript attempt to access frame with url" message.
So I got confused...Anyone can help?

Comment: Close and reopen cmd. If this doesn't work, restart.

Comment: The *Unsafe javascript....* is a known issue: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12697 You can still use the script, because this happens only on exit.

Comment: Is this bug comes from phantomjs 1.9.8 or comes from casperjs1.1.0 beta3?

Comment: It's from PhantomJS 1.9.8. You could downgrade to 1.9.7, but then you would have to run with `--ssl-protocol=any` for https sites.

Comment: how to downgrade the version?